# Avatar background color not changing dynamically in material-ui v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to change each avatar background color on the basis of categories, for example if the category is "work" then the avatar color must be yellow if the category is "todos" then the avatar color must be pink and so on. But the code is displaying the default grey background-color of each avatar. I'm unable to change the background-color.

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardHeader from "@mui/material/CardHeader";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import { IconButton, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { DeleteOutlined } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import { blue, green, pink, yellow } from "@mui/material/colors";
import Avatar from "@mui/material/Avatar";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  avatar: {
    backgroundColor: (note) => {
      if (note.category == "work") {
        return yellow[700];
      }
      if (note.category == "money") {
        return green[500];
      }
      if (note.category == "todos") {
        return pink[500];
      }
      return blue[500];
    },
  },
});

const NoteCard = ({ note, handleDelete }) => {
  const classes = useStyles(note);

  return (
    <div>
      <Card elevation={1}>
        <CardHeader
          avatar={
            <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
              {note.category[0].toUpperCase()}
            </Avatar>
          }
          action={
            <IconButton onClick={() => handleDelete(note.id)}>
              <DeleteOutlined />
            </IconButton>
          }
          title={note.title}
          subheader={note.category}
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
            {note.details}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NoteCard;
```

[video reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEbSx5CCgSc&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gjxLvV4VEkZ6H6H4yWuS58&index=17)

Comment: You should use `styled` function instead of `makeStyles` in MUI v5 anyway. `makeStyles` is a legacy API that is not recommended in the new version and may be removed in v6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/) to create minor style adjustments like this, for example:

1. define a function that takes a note and returns a color:

```
const getAvatarBgColor = ({ category }) => ({
  work: yellow[700],
  money: green[500],
  todos: pink[500],
}[category] || blue[500]);
```

2. Use the function to apply color within the sx prop (note the `bgcolor` property vs `backgroundColor`):

```html
<Avatar sx={{ bgcolor: getAvatarBgColor(note) }}>
  {note.category[0].toUpperCase()}
</Avatar>
```

[Take a look at the example by MUI here](https://mui.com/components/avatars/#letter-avatars) for more options.

---

Alternatively, if you want to keep the `makeStyles` way of applying styles, look into [tss-react](https://github.com/garronej/tss-react) as it's the [recommended package by MUI](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#migrate-from-jss) to use.

Answer (score 0):

The [`sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/) is a shortcut for defining custom style.

1.Create a function:

```
 const avatarBgColor = (note) => {
      if (note.category === "work") {
        return yellow[700];
      }
      if (note.category === "money") {
        return green[700];
      }
      if (note.category === "todos") {
        return pink[500];
      } else {
        return blue[500];
      }
    };
```

2.Use the function inside the sx prop

```
<Avatar sx={{ bgcolor: avatarBgColor(note) }}>
              {note.category[0].toUpperCase()}
</Avatar>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case none of the previous answers worked for you, an option is to try to use the plain `style` attribute to apply custom styling.

```
<Avatar style={{ backgroundColor: Color.info }}>
   {/* Your code */}
</Avatar>
```